# I need help converting from base 36 to base 10

Tags: lua

As an example, I want to convert:

1j16qd5g0lc

To:

5589146303201280

But currently ‘tonumber’ converts it to:

5.5891463032013e+15

I understand that there is a bit.tonumber function that might work better but that function is not available to me. Could someone implement what I need easily? I am not too familiar Lua.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you attempted implementing it yourself?

Comment: I imagine something like the Base36Decode function on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36#C.23_implementation can be converted to Lua but since I am not too familiar with Lua, I can't figure it out.

Comment: So you need to have the output be a number? Lua numbers cannot be that large, so your only hope is string or a large numbers library (which probably splits a number into several parts using tables).

Comment: My final output needs to be a string of the number. Maybe the conversion could possibly be done in chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `print(string.format("%.0f",tonumber("1j16qd5g0lc",36)))`.